# Unusal boot time of one hour, where to find logs

Tags: boot, raspberry-pi, raspbian, dmesg

I have an unusual time of boot of aprox one hour on a RPI.

After one minute I can ping the device, but I can't do an ssh after until 1 hour. I don't know where to find logs to hep me. I checked /var/log/syslog, that doesn't show anything estrange, and in dmesg I found this:

```
[Sat Mar 17 12:50:44 2018] mmc0: timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[Sat Mar 17 12:50:44 2018] mmc0: cmd op 17 arg 0x9e204f flags 0xb5 - resp 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000, err 0
[Sat Mar 17 12:50:44 2018] mmc0: data blocks 1 blksz 200 - err 0
[Sat Mar 17 12:50:44 2018] mmc0: =========== REGISTER DUMP ===========
[Sat Mar 17 12:50:44 2018] mmc0: SDCMD  0x00004051
[Sat Mar 17 12:50:44 2018] mmc0: SDARG  0x009e204f
[Sat Mar 17 12:50:44 2018] mmc0: SDTOUT 0x017d7840
[Sat Mar 17 12:50:44 2018] mmc0: SDCDIV 0x00000003
[Sat Mar 17 12:50:44 2018] mmc0: SDRSP0 0x00000900
[Sat Mar 17 12:50:44 2018] mmc0: SDRSP1 0x00001133
[Sat Mar 17 12:50:44 2018] mmc0: SDRSP2 0xffffffff
[Sat Mar 17 12:50:44 2018] mmc0: SDRSP3 0x0202403a
[Sat Mar 17 12:50:44 2018] mmc0: SDHSTS 0x00000080
[Sat Mar 17 12:50:44 2018] mmc0: SDVDD  0x00000001
[Sat Mar 17 12:50:44 2018] mmc0: SDEDM  0x00010801
[Sat Mar 17 12:50:44 2018] mmc0: SDHCFG 0x0000041e
[Sat Mar 17 12:50:44 2018] mmc0: SDHBCT 0x00000200
[Sat Mar 17 12:50:44 2018] mmc0: SDHBLC 0x00000000
[Sat Mar 17 12:50:44 2018] mmc0: ===========================================
[Sat Mar 17 12:50:44 2018] mmcblk0: error -110 transferring data, sector 10362959, nr 1, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
[Sat Mar 17 12:50:44 2018] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 10362959
```

Also looking on `journalctl -b` (edited: you must be root, not tested)

```
$ journalctl -b
No journal files were found.
```

After ssh login everything seems to work fine.

Thanks in advance!

**EDITED 29/03/2018**

- Using a screen it stops on `Started update UTMP about system Runlevel Changes.` until  between 30~45 minutes.
- I dd all the SD to a new one and the boot time is normal.

Comment: Do you have the option of connecting a keyboard and screen to the pi so you can see what's going on in realtime without needing to ssh? As for the logs, see `journalctl -b`. Can you see where it gets stuck there?

Comment: Do you have the option of switching your sd card to a new/another one? For starters I would just dump the old and flag that image to the new one.

Comment: @terdon I will try to manage a screen tomorrow. And also try to dump old card to new one..

Comment: I'm on mobile now, so I can't check but I think raspbian needs you to enable logs. See if you can find anything relevant on Google

Comment: @terdon I search in google, to see journalctl you must be root..

Comment: So it appears to have been a hardware problem with the previous SD card?

Comment: Yes it seems, I'm doing the last tests to write a good answer with all the process that I'm following.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem as described below (as [suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/431921/112572) by @buddika):

- First I tried with a new compatible sd card, doing a copy of the whole card.

To make disk image:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb conv=sync,noerror status=progress bs=64K | gzip -c > rpi.gz
```

And to restore the image:

```
gunzip -c rpi.gz | dd of=/dev/sdb status=progress
```

- After check that normal boot time on the new sd, I started to check the old one for bad sectors.

To find bad sectors I used:

```
sudo badblocks -vv /dev/sdb2
```

After find bad blocks I re-burned the rpi.gz image and execute the command to repair the blocks:

```
sudo  fsck -cct ext4 /dev/sdb2
```

After that the boot time is normal again.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be an issue with your SD card. Did you try it with another one?
Found a similar issue here,[raspberrypi-sd-issue](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=7530)

Comment: After try a new sd, using dd command, it works fine. I used badblocks to check my sd, and found some bad blocks.